# Pandas: Dealing with a column with multiple data types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a column in my dataframe df, which contains values of type float and str:

```
df['ESTACD'].unique()

Output:
array([11.0, 32.0, 31.0, 35.0, 37.0, 84.0, 83.0, 81.0, 97.0, 39.0,
   38.0, 40.0, 34.0, 7.0, 17.0, 16.0, 14.0, 82.0, 8.0, '11', '40',
   '31', '39', '68', '97', '32', '33', '37', '38', '83', '84', '93',
   '35', '81', '67', '07', '80', '71', 'A3', '14', '17', '22', '34',
   '36', '82', '08'], dtype=object)
```

I wish to convert all values of this column to type string. Using `astype(str)` is not enough here since we end up with values like '11.0', '32.0', etc.

The only other way I could think of is using a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if (type(df['ESTACD'][i]) == float) or (df['ESTACD'][i].startswith('0')):
        df['ESTACD'][i] = str(int(df['ESTACD'][i]))
```

However, this is very time consuming on large datasets. Is there a way to implement this without a loop?

Comment: What should values like `'08'` become? `8` or stay as `08`?

Comment: They must be converted to 8, which is what the second part of the or does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think here should be very fast use pure python like:

```
df['ESTACD'] = [str(int(x)) if isinstance(x, float) else x for x in df['ESTACD']]
```